# Invalid redeclaration of typealias

Tags: swift, generics

I have a generic protocol, `TwoWayBindDelegate`, that uses the generic associated type to determine the parameters of the function `twoWayBind()`

```
protocol TwoWayBindDelegate: class {

    associatedtype BindType

    func twoWayBind(to observable: Observable<BindType>?, observableChanged: ((BindType) -> ())?)
}
```

I then created a class, `Reactive<Base: UIView, Type>` (which conforms to `TwoWayBindDelegate`) where you have to initialize it with the generic `Base`. For eg: `let reactiveSlider = Reacive<UISlider>(slider)`.

My issue is when I am extending Reactive and conforming to `TwoWayBindDelegate`, I get an error `Invalid redeclaration of 'BindType'` because I am declaring `BindType` and `twoWayBind()` in both my extensions. Is there a way I can have both extensions provide different implementations for `TwoWayBindDelegate`

```
class Reactive<Base: UIView>: TwoWayBindDelegate {

    public var base: Base

    init(base: Base) {
        self.base = base
    }
}

extension Reactive where Base == UISlider {

    typealias BindType = Float        

    func twoWayBind(to observable: Observable<Float>?, observableChanged: ((Float) -> ())?) {
        // implement two way bind for UISlider
    }
}

extension Reactive where Base == UITextField {

    typealias BindType = String        

    func twoWayBind(to observable: Observable<String>?, observableChanged: ((String) -> ())?) {
        // implement two way bind for UITextField
    }
}
```

I did some research and found out that it may be a bug https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5392. Does there happen to be a workaround

Comment: I'm using `BindType` so that the parameter in `twoWayBind()` can be of type `BindType`. So if  `BindType` a String the parameter will be Observable<String>. If I get rid of the associated type what would the parameters of the protocol function be of type? I don't have a whole lot of experience with generics so I correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: It seems to me that you have it backwards. If you say `Observable<String>` in the declaration, we _know_ that BindType must be String; the generic is resolved. See my answer below and please correct _me_ if _I'm_ wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite see what the `typealias` is for. The function declaration alone is sufficient to tell the compiler what `BindType` must be.

The problem I found with your code (apart from the missing Observable declaration, of course) is that the Reactive class *itself* doesn't conform to TwoWayBindDelegate. To get around that, I threw in an arbitrary implementation of `twoWayBind`. When I did, and when I deleted the unnecessary `typealias` declarations, your code compiled for me:

```
struct Observable<T> {}

protocol TwoWayBindDelegate: class {
    associatedtype BindType
    func twoWayBind(to observable: Observable<BindType>?, observableChanged: ((BindType) -> ())?)
}

class Reactive<Base: UIView>: TwoWayBindDelegate {
    public var base: Base
    init(base: Base) {
        self.base = base
    }
    func twoWayBind(to observable: Observable<Int>?, observableChanged: ((Int) -> ())?) {
    }
}

extension Reactive where Base == UISlider {
    func twoWayBind(to observable: Observable<Float>?, observableChanged: ((Float) -> ())?) {
    }
}

extension Reactive where Base == UITextField {
    func twoWayBind(to observable: Observable<String>?, observableChanged: ((String) -> ())?) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works great! Just to be clear, the `twoWayBind()` declared in the base class only runs if `Base` is not a `UISlider` or `UITextField` right?

Comment: Try it and see!

Comment: By the way, I should add that the problem you're having is in no small part due to the (in my opinion) extremely unfortunate secondary use of the reserved word `typealias` as a way to resolve explicitly a protocol generic `associatedtype`. I filed a bug report on this (rdar://24792823) but made no headway.

Comment: @matt Hey Matt, can you give a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/q/66154789/1404324 maybe you can help me out. It seems my problem is relevant to this solution somehow.